# Is it possible to save crashes log to an email using Fabric Crashlytics in android?

Tags: android, appfabric, twitter-fabric, google-fabric

I am developing an android app, and I used Fabric Crashlytics to see my crashes, it works well but I want Fabric to send the crashes logs to an email and then I see them from my email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, after searching, I find out that Fabric **will automatically send** all crashes to your email (email that you have signed up with).